# Dynamically set HREF value within modal window (bootstrap/jquery)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to add change the value of an HREF within a modal based on the various links that users click on to activate the modal.

For instance I have 3 links which open the exact same modal window:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Modal-1</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Modal-2</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Modal-3</a>
```

The information contained in the modal window is the same for all 3, but the  tag **within** the modal window will redirect to a different location based on the link the user clicked on to open the modal.

Here's the modal markup:

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
      <h1 class="modal-title">My Modal Window</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>My copy goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <a id="closemodal" href="DEPENDS ON LINKED CLICKED TO OPEN MODAL" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">GO</a>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery attr(key, value) to change href of hyperlink.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" data-link="google.com">Modal-1</a>

$('a').click(function() 
{
    $('#closemodal').attr('href', $(this).data('link'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaofgend/3/

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.